# What are "blue" questions?

Tags: support

I noticed today that some questions on the Parent site seem highlighted in blue, but I can't find an obvious differentiator between these and other questions.  Was there a recent change to the system?  What qualities causes a question to be highlighted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blue questions are those that have "interesting" tags. 
Faded questions are those that have "ignored" tags.
Everything else renders normally.

Answer (score 11):

I just noticed the reason, now.  I had added some tags to the "Interesting" list in my profile, and it seems the blue questions are the ones that have these tags.

Don't mind me.

Comment: You should accept your answer when you get the chance. :)

Comment: Yea, this was useful.  I wasn't using that functionality as their aren't *that* many questions coming thru that I can't keep up.  But I do like the highlighting :)  Thanks!

Comment: @yhw42 - Thanks for the reminder.  I think there's a timer of 24 or 48 hours before you can accept your own answer.